# vba - setting a numeric array and comparing it to a cell

Tags: arrays, vba

I have this code:

```
Sub PipelineStatusConvert()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim tgt As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Object
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("1", "2", "3")  '4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng1 = ws.Range("K13:K1000")

'    If Intersect(ActiveCell, rng1) Is Nothing Then
'
'        MsgBox "The active cell does NOT Intersect " & rng1.Address
'
'    Else
'
'        MsgBox "The active cell does Intersect " & rng1.Address
'
'    End If

For Each cell In rng1

 'evaluate something

    If cell <> myarray Then
    MsgBox "no intersection"
'   MsgBox cell.Address
    End If

 '   Select Case
  '  Case 1

Next cell

End Sub
```

I am trying to run a check on each cell in the range selected and say that if the cell's value is not in the array (1-3), then

'do something..

I keep running into the "Type Mismatch error". I know it has to do with the array declaration as I think it's trying to compare a cell value to an array (which won't work).

How would I re-strcuture this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a function to search an array for a value.  Modifying your code a little, I came up with the following:

```
Sub PipelineStatusConvert()
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim tgt As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim myarray As Variant

   myarray = Array("1", "2", "3")  '4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

   Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   Set rng1 = ws.Range("K13:K1000")

   For Each cell In rng1
       If Not isInArray(cell.Value, myarray) Then
          MsgBox "no intersection"
       End If
   Next
End Sub

Function isInArray(Match As String, SourceArray As Variant) As Boolean
   isInArray = (UBound(Filter(SourceArray, Match)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this., I;ll keep it in the back pocket. I actually was able to resolve this with the LIKE operator and a wildcard!